# Error using Google.Apis.AnalyticsData.v1beta.Data to get data from GA4

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

I am using c# to retrieve a report from Google Analytics (GA4) using Google.Apis.AnalyticsData.v1beta. Following an example from https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/quickstart-client-libraries#.net_1. Code below. I am getting the very generic error of "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" on the request.

string propertyId = "123456";

```
        // Credential Path
        string credentialsPath = @"C:\\client_secret_new.json";


        // Authenticate and create the service.
        GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile(credentialsPath);
        AnalyticsDataService service = new AnalyticsDataService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = "Google Analytics 4",
        });

        // Construct the request.
        RunReportRequest request = new RunReportRequest()
        {

            Property = $"properties/{propertyId}",

            DateRanges =
            {
                new DateRange()
                {
                    StartDate = "2023-10-1",
                    EndDate = "2023-10-30"
                }
            },

            Dimensions =
            {
                new Dimension()
                {
                    Name = "date"
                },
                new Dimension()
                {
                    Name = "landingPagePlusQueryString"
                },
                new Dimension()
                {
                    Name = "medium"
                },
                //new Dimension()
                //{
                //    Name = "orderCoupon"
                //},
                new Dimension()
                {
                    Name = "sourceMedium"
                },
                new Dimension()
                {
                    Name = "transactionId"
                }
            },

            Metrics =
            {
                new Metric()
                {
                    Name = "sessions"
                }
                //,
                //new Metric()
                //{
                //    Name = "totalRevenue"
                //}
            },

        };

        // Execute request.
        RunReportResponse response = service.Properties.RunReport(request,propertyId).Execute();
            

        // Print the results.
        Console.WriteLine("Report result:");
        foreach (Row row in response.Rows)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", row.DimensionValues[0].Value, row.MetricValues[0].Value);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```